# How do I delete a specific array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am building a widget I created banner ads to its expiration date (in 
wordpress)

```
array(2) {
  [7]=>array(2) {
    ["title"]=>string(3) "ads"
    ["number"]=>int(2)
    [1]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/120-3.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2017/03/10"
    }
    [2]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/120-3.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2016/10/20"
    }
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>int(1)
}
```

And would like to apply as follows: (Delete key [2])

```
array(2) {
  [7]=>array(2) {
    ["title"]=>string(3) "ads"
    ["number"]=>int(2)
    [1]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/120-3.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2017/03/10"
    }
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>int(1)
}
```

For this I wrote the following code in the function.php:

```
function remove_expired_ads(){
    $widgets = get_option('widget_ads_banner_sidebars');
    $count = count($widgets);
    for ($x=1; $x<=$count ;$x++ ){
        foreach ( $widgets as $key => $w){
            if (!is_array( $w )) continue ;
            if(!empty($w[$x]['expire'])) {

                $today_date = date('Ymd');
                $expire_date = $w[$x]['expire'];
                $expire_year = substr($expire_date, 0, 4);
                $expire_month = substr($expire_date, 5, 2);
                $expire_day = substr($expire_date, 8, 2);
                $expire_time = $expire_year . $expire_month . $expire_day;

                if (($today_date >= $expire_time)) {

                    //dd($widgets[$key][$x]);
                    unset($widgets[$key][$x]); 
                    //If this method to write the entire arrays will be deleted  unset($widgets[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    update_option('widget_ads_banner_sidebars', $widgets , true);
}
add_action('widgets_init','remove_expired_ads');
```

But the result is as follows:

```
array(2) {
  [7]=>array(2) {
    ["title"]=>string(3) "ads"
    ["number"]=>int(2)
    [1]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/120-3.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2017/03/10"
    }
    [2]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(0) ""
      ["expire"]=>string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>int(1)
}
```

**UPDATE**
When I print my own code result

```
array(2) {
  ["address-image"]=>
  string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/120-3.jpg"
  ["expire"]=>
  string(10) "2016/10/20"
}
```

How do I access key (key [2])

Sorry, my English is not very good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this loop:

```
$now = strtotime('now');

foreach ($widgets as $key => $widget) {
    if (!is_array($widget)) {
        continue;
    }

    $noOfAdds = 0;
    $widget = array_filter($widget, function ($ad) use (&$noOfAdds, $now) {
        if (!is_array($ad) || !isset($ad['expire'])) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($now >= strtotime($ad['expire'])) {
            return false;
        }

        $noOfAdds += 1;
        return true;
    });

    if ($noOfAdds) {
        $widgets[$key] = $widget;
        $widgets[$key]['number'] = $noOfAdds;
        continue;
    }

    unset($widgets[$key]);
}
```

We use `foreach` to traverse widgets and [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter out expired ads. If all ads of the widget are expired the widget is unset. If there valid ads in the widget the number is updated. I have used [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to make dates comparable.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a44291cf577e2e57938be695e85b771fcff23cbf).

Answer (score 0):

`Unset()` should work if you are targeting the correct key=>value. Ive updated the way you check the expiry. Implement it and see if it makes any difference.

```
function remove_expired_ads(){
    $widgets = get_option('widget_ads_banner_sidebars');
    $count = count($widgets);
    for ($x=1; $x<=$count ;$x++ ){
        foreach ( $widgets as $key => $w){
            if (!is_array( $w )) continue ;
            if(!empty($w[$x]['expire'])) {

               $expire_date = strtotime($w[$x]['expire']);

                if ((time() >= $expire_time)) {
                    unset($widgets[$key][$x]);     
                }
            }
        }
    }

    update_option('widget_ads_banner_sidebars', $widgets , true);
}
add_action('widgets_init','remove_expired_ads');
```

Comment: Are you still getting the same result?

Comment: I do not have access to the key

Comment: I separate arrays are printed without checking whether expired or not