# How to Change Array a Special key to numeric in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following code to remove array, but I think there's a problem

[How do I delete a specific array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013921/how-do-i-delete-a-specific-array-in-php/41022231#41022231)

```
 array(2) {
  [7]=>array(3) {
    ["title"]=>string(3) "ads"
    ["number"]=>int(3)
    [1]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/120-3.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2017/03/10"
    }
    [2]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/240.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2016/10/20"
    }
    [3]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/300.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2016/12/28"
    }
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>int(1)
}
```

After the run:

```
array(2) {
  [7]=>array(2) {
    ["title"]=>string(3) "ads"
    ["number"]=>int(2)
    [1]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/120-3.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2017/03/10"
    }
    [3]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/300.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2016/12/28"
    }
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>int(1)
}
```

But I want to be changed later be removed as follows (Key changes from [3] to [2]):

```
array(2) {
  [7]=>array(2) {
    ["title"]=>string(3) "ads"
    ["number"]=>int(2)
    [1]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/120-3.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2017/03/10"
    }
    [2]=>array(2) {
      ["address-image"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/300.jpg"
      ["expire"]=>string(10) "2016/12/28"
    }
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>int(1)
}
```

Sorry, my English is not very good

Thank you

Comment: Why the key is almost irrelevant. Use `foreach` and who cares

Comment: If you want to change index from `[3]` to `[2]`, use `array_values` function. It reindexes and returns array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new array using `array_values`:
For example:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);

unset($arr[0]);
$arr = array_values($arr);

print_r($arr);
//Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

After delete use `array_merge()` function

```
unset($data[7]["number"][2]);
$data[7]["number"] = array_merge($data[7]["number"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Assume `$a` is storing your array and want to swap the array key 2 and 3.

```
$a[3] ^= $a[2] ^= $a[3] ^= $a[2];
```

after swap then unset the element you wish to remove.